# Как происходит передача пароля роутеру по wifi?

Tags: безопасность, криптография, шифрование, wifi, пароль

1. Как происходит первая передача пароля от мобильного устройства роутеру? Шифруется ли пароль?
2. Предполагаю что пароль шифруется открытым ключем который роутер говорит устройству при подключении?
3. Если 2 верно, то как мобильное устройство может быть уверено что ей свой открытый ключ сообщил именно нужный роутер, а не какой то поставленный рядом злоумышленником? Ведь данные все передаются "по воздуху" и все их видят и могут сами генерировать.

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос. О какой схеме аутентификации вы спрашиваете - WPA-PSK, какая-то из схем EAP, PEAP и т.п.?

Comment: @PakUula На самом деле меня интересует общий подход, ни какой то конкретной схеме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вас интересует схема аутентификации "вообще", то такой нет. В Wi-Fi стандартизированы несколько схем аутентификации. В бытовых роутерах наиболее часто используется схема аутентификации **WPA-PSK** (она же WPA-Personal). Спецификация называется **IEEE 802.11i**

В этой спецификации точка доступа и станция (т.е. устройство пользователя) взаимно аутентифицируются только в том случае, если они знают одинаковый общий пароль, так называемый pre-shared key (PSK).

Сразу отвечу на ваши вопросы:

1. Пароль не передаётся по сети ни в каком виде.
2. Соответственно, его не требуется шифровать.
3. Станция (мобильное устройство) сможет корректно взаимодействовать только с той точкой доступа, которая знает пароль и предоставляет сеть с заданным именем. Если враги смогли узнать пароль и раздают сеть с тем же именем, что и правильная точка доступа, то WPA Personal никак не сможет догадаться, что это враги. Мобильное устройство успешно аутентифицируется с такой вражеской точкой доступа.

Более развёрнуто.

Из пароля станция и точка доступа независимо генерируют взаимный мастер-ключ (Pairwise master key, **PMK**): `PMK = PBKDF2(hashFn=HMAC−SHA1, hashKey=passphrase, salt=ssid, rounds=4096, outSize=256)` Если по-русски, то для получения ключа стороны 4096 раза хэшируют идентификатор сети криптографической хэш функцией (HMAC), используя бинарное представление пароля как ключ HMAC (схема называется [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)). То есть

Но и этот ключ не передают по сети. Чтобы подтвердить знание секрета, стороны обмениваются случайными числами (nonce-ами) , из которых генерируют взаимный временный ключ (**PTK**).

Когда мобильное устройство обращается к точке доступа с запросом на аутентификацию, та стартует четырехэтапный аутентификационный обмен (**four step handshake**). В первом сообщение точка доступа посылает станции случайное число, ANonce. Получив это сообщение станция генерирует своё случайное число, SNonce, и из этих случайных чисел и PMK генерирует PTK: `PTK = RANDOM_FN(PMK, ANonce, SNonce, AP_MAC, Station_MAC)`. То есть PTK есть результат применения псевдо-случайной функции, инициализированной конкатенацией байтовых последовательностей общего ключа, сгенерированного из пароля, случайных чисел, сгенерированных точкой доступа и станцией, и МАС-адресов станции и точки доступа.

И этот ключ тоже не передают по сети. Вместо этого станция формирует сообщение с SNonce и включает в него имитовставку (message integrity code, MIC). В первой версии WPA для вычисления этого кода использовали HMAC-MD5 с ключом PTK, во второй версии стали использовать CCM-MIC, то есть шифруют сообщение шифром AES с ключом PSK и в качестве кода целостности берут последний блок. Точка доступа, получив SNonce, формирует PTK на своей стороне и вычисляет с этим ключом код MIC для полученного сообщения.

Если вычисление дало тот же результат, что и код MIC вычисленный станцией, значит у **станции и точки доступа одинаковые ключи PTK**. Раз у них одинаковые ключи PTK, значит, **у них одинаковые ключи PMK**. А раз у них одинаковые ключи PMK, значит, **у них одинаковые пароли**.

Когда точка доступа убеждается, что у станции тот же пароль, то она формирует третье сообщение и в него вставляет MIС, вычисленный с ключом PTK и установленным битом `Install`. Тем самым точка доступа подтверждает аутентификацию станции показывает, что она сгенерировала тот же ключ, что и станция.

Четвертым сообщением станция подтверждает аутентификацию точки доступа.

Пароль не пересылается по сети. Вместо этого используются механизмы генерации ключей, которые гарантируют малую вероятность коллизии - то есть генерируются одинаковые ключи, несмотря на разные пароли.

Comment: По-моему с последним предложением что-то не так

Comment: @PakUula 1) Если этот самый ключ будет перехвачен и воспроизведен третье стороной то он уже не будет действовать? 2) После того как станция и точка доступа убедились что они знают общий пароль, станция отправляет какой то открытый ключ для дальнейшего шифрования сообщения?